# script for testing if number is in interval

Tags: shell

I am trying to test if a number is in the interval [1;100] here is what I did:

```
   var=10
   if [ $["$var" -gt "1" ] -a $["$var" -lt "100"] ] ; then
            echo "yes"
   else
            echo "no"
    fi
```

however when I run the script I get the error message:
      ./yourscript:line 2 10 -gt 1:error syntax in expression ,any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

delete unnecessaries and use `&&`:

```
var=10
if [ $var -gt 1 ] && [ $var -lt 100 ] ; then #or with -a if [ $var -gt 1 -a $var -lt 100 ] ;
   echo "yes"
else
   echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: nothing. just when using && syntax must be: [ condition ]  && [ condition ]. if u want use -a it will be like this: if [ $var -gt 1 -a $var -lt 100 ] ;